# Does DNX core 5.0 support SignalR 2.2.0?

Tags: c#, signalr, dnx50

I am new to SignalR and have to use it in my upcoming project but I am stuck on an error with references. The problem is that signalR 2.2.0 is available in DNX 4.5.1 but not available in DNX Core 5.0 and I am getting errors such as

> "The type or namespace name 'SignalR' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNet'"

So my question is, if signalR 2.2.0 is not supported by DNX Core 5.0 is there any way to fix that or force my app to use only DNX 4.5.1?

Comment: dnx is not a thing anymore. it was replaced by dotnet and the whole project just shipped a week ago as ASP.NET Core 1.0. Anyways, if you are asking about the server I don't think you will be able to use 2.x server in ASP.NET Core app - you need to try this: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server

Comment: Use the proper terms, such as .NET Framework, instead of obsolete ones.

Comment: Seems like i solved my problem with dependency delete from project.json where i deleted DNX Core 5.0 dependency so i forced my app to use only 4.5.1